# Splitting field of a separable polynomial is separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Probably a stupid question, but..

Why is the splitting field of a separable polynomial necessarily separable?

Thanks.

**Follow up question**

Show that if $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ for $P \in K[X]$, then $[F:K] \leq n!$

I've proven this by induction on $n$, but I'm convinced there's a more algebraic approach ($n!$ screams $S_n$).

If I knew $P$ were separable, then I'd know $F$ was Galois, so $ |\mbox{Gal}(F/K)| = [F:K] $. Considering the action of $ \mbox{Gal}(F/K) $ on the roots of $P$, we'd get an injective homomorphism into $ S_n $, giving the result.

But $P$ is not given to be separable, so $P$ could have repeated roots when factorised in $F$. If $G$ is any finite group of $K$-automorphisms of $L$, then I know that $[F:K] \leq |G| $. Considering the action of $G$ on the set of roots of $P$, say $\Omega$, we get an injective homomorphism of $G$ into $S_{|\Omega|}$, where $|\Omega| \leq n$ (I think). I have a feeling I'm wrong here, since I think $G$ is forced to be $\mbox{Aut}(F/K)$. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Because it is generated by elements which are roots of separable polynomials!

Comment: I think the key point is that a finite degree extension $E/F$ is separable if and only if its degree is equal to the number of $F$-embeddings of $E$ into some fixed algebraic closure of $F$. (The question doesn't look stupid to me. +1)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Please note I've added a follow up question to my original post.

Comment: I think it suffices to understand the case of a *simple* (algebraic) extension.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is there a way to patch my proof to make it work for $P$ not separable?

Comment: Dear @Anon: In case your last comment was for me (by the way, you should use the `@` sign in such situations): When you write: "Show that if $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ for $P\in K[X]$, then $[F:K]\leq n!$", you mean that $n$ is the degree of $P$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $P$ in $F$, let $Q$ be its minimal polynomial over $K$, and put $d:=\deg Q$. Then: $[K(\alpha):K]=d\le n$, $Q$ divides $P$, $F$ is a splitting field over $K(\alpha)$ for $P/Q$, $\deg P/Q=n-d$, $[F:K(\alpha)]=[F:K]/d$, and an obvious induction completes the proof.

Comment: Dear @Anon: To come back to this separability question: You can define a separable extension as an extension generated by separable elements, or as an extension all of whose elements are separable; but it's crucial (in my opinion) that you understand why the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Dear @Pierre-YvesGaillard: Thank you very much for your help. I've consulted the relevant section of my notes, and now "see" the relevance of certain propositions (like your first post above).

Comment: Dear Anon: You're welcome. In both cases, I think the key point is to understand the correspondence between: (1) the $K$-embeddings of $K(\alpha)$ ($\alpha$ algebraic) into an extension $L/K$, and (2) the roots in $L$ of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### New Answer

[New version of the new answer. Thank you very much to KCd! --- See his comment.]

The simplest, I think, is to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory (FTGT) for a normal extension $E/F$ generated by finitely many separable elements, and to obtain the fact that all the elements of $E$ are separable over $F$ as a corollary.

The point is that the FTGT can be given a very short proof, which will be described below. (I of course believe that this proof is complete. Thanks for correcting me if I'm wrong.)

> **FTGT** (Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory). Let $F$ be a field, let $A$ be an algebraic closure of $F$, let $p\in F[X]$ be a product of separable irreducible polynomials, let $E$ be a splitting field for $p$ over $F$, and let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be the roots of $p$ in $E$. Then
>
> - the group $G$ of $F$-automorphisms of $E/F$ is finite,
> - there is a bijective correspondence between the sub-extensions $S/F$ of $E/F$ and the subgroups $H$ of $G$, and we have
>     $$
>   S\leftrightarrow H\iff H=\text{Aut}_S E\iff S=E^H\implies[E:S]=|H|,
>   $$
>     where $E^H$ is the fixed subfield of $H$, where $[E:S]$ is the degree (that is the dimension) of $E$ over $S$, and where $|H|$ is the order of $H$.

We are taking for granted

$(1)$ the universal property of a simple algebraic extension, and

$(2)$ the existence and universal property of our splitting field $E$,

which we briefly recall:

$(1)$ If $a$ is algebraic over a field $K$, then the $K$-embeddings of $K(a)$ in an extension $L$ of $K$ are in natural bijection with the roots in $L$ of the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$.

$(2)$ Any root of $p$ in any extension of $E$ is in $E$, and $E$ is generated over $F$ by the roots $a_i$ of $p$. Moreover, if $S/F$ is a sub-extension of $E/F$, then any $F$-embedding of $S$ in $E$ extends to an $F$-automorphism of $E$.

Going back to the assumptions of the FTGT, we claim:

$(3)$ If $S/F$ is a sub-extension of $E/F$, then $[E:S]=|\text{Aut}_S E|$.

$(4)$ If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $|H|=[E:E^H]$.

**Proof that (3) and (4) imply the FTGT.** Let $S/F$ be a sub-extension of $E/F$ and put $H:=\text{Aut}_S E$. Then we have trivially $S\subset E^H$, and $(3)$ and $(4)$ imply 
$$
[E:S]=[E:E^H].
$$
Conversely let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and set $\overline H:=\text{Aut}_{E^H}E$. Then we have trivially $H\subset\overline H$, and $(3)$ and $(4)$ imply $|H|=|\overline H|$.

To prove that any element $a$ of $E$ is separable over $F$, put $H:=\text{Aut}_{F(a)}E$, and note that the set of $F$-embeddings of $F(a)$ in $E$ is in natural bijection with the set $G/H$, whose cardinality is, by the FTGT, equal to $[F(a):F]$.

**Proof of (3).** The statement follows from the fact that any $F$-embedding of $S_i:=S(a_1,\dots,a_i)$ in $E$ has exactly $[S_{i+1}:S_i]$ extensions to $S_{i+1}$.

**Proof of (4).** In view of (3) it is enough to check $|H|\ge[E:E^H]$. Let $k$ be an integer larger than $|H|$, and pick a 
$$
b=(b_1,\dots,b_k)\in E^k.
$$
We must show that the $b_i$ are linearly dependent over $E^H$, or equivalently that $b^\perp\cap(E^H)^k$ is nonzero, where $?^\perp$ denotes the vectors orthogonal to ? in $E^k$ with respect to the dot product on $E^k$. Any element of $b^\perp \cap (E^H)^k$ is necessarily orthogonal to $h(b)$ for any $h \in H$, so  $b^\perp \cap (E^H)^k = (Hb)^\perp \cap (E^H)^k$, where $Hb$ is the $H$-orbit of $H$. We will show $(Hb)^\perp \cap (E^H)^k$ is nonzero. Since the span of $Hb$ in $E^k$ has $E$-dimension at most $|H| < k$, $(Hb)^\perp$ is nonzero. Choose a nonzero vector $x$ in $(Hb)^\perp$ such that $x_i=0$ for the largest number of $i$ as possible among all nonzero vectors in $(Hb)^\perp$. Some coordinate $x_j$ is nonzero in $E$, so by scaling we can assume $x_j = 1$ for some $j$. Since the subspace $(Hb)^\perp$ in $E^k$ is stable under the action of $H$, for any $h$ in $H$ we have $h(x) \in (Hb)^\perp$, so $h(x)-x \in (Hb)^\perp$. Since $x_j = 1$, the $j$-th coordinate of $h(x) - x$ is $0$, so $h(x)-x = 0$ by the choice of $x$. Since this holds for all $h$ in $H$, $x$ is in $(E^H)^k$.

### Old Answer

This is more a hint than an answer. I think the key point here is to understand the equivalence between various definitions of a *separable extension*. I'll just try to emphasize some of the basic facts.

Let $K$ be a field, $A/K$ an algebraic closure, and $L/K$ an extension of degree $d < \infty$ contained in $A$. We claim that the following conditions are equivalent:

(1) $L/K$ is generated by separable elements,

(2) each element of $L$ is separable over $K$,

(3) there are exactly $d$ embeddings of $L$ in $A$ over $K$.

We say that $L/K$ is **separable** if it satisfies these conditions. Let's sketch a proof of the equivalence.

Say that the number, denoted by $[L:K]_s$, of $K$-embeddings of $L$ in $A$ is the *separable degree* of $L/K$.

Let $M$ be a finite degree extension of $K$ contained in $A$, and $L$ a field between $K$ and $M$. We claim:

(4) $[M:K]_s=[M:L]_s\ [L:K]_s$.

This is an easy, but instructive, exercise.

Claim: (1) and (3) are equivalent when $K$ is generated by a single element $\alpha$. Indeed, if $f\in K[X]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then $[L:K]$ is the degree of $f$, whereas $[L:K]_s$ is the number of distinct roots of $f$ in $A$.

In view of (4), the above claim implies that (1), (2) and (3) are equivalent in the general case.

As a corollary, we see that a finite degree extension $L/K$ contains a largest separable sub-extension $S$, and that $[S:K]=[L:K]_s$.

As a corollary to the corollary, we get the fact suggested by the notation that the integer $[L:K]_s$ does not depend on the choice of an algebraic closure of $L$.

Comment: In your new answer, there is no serious use made of algebraic closures: you just need splitting fields, which are logically simpler. Also when you write "Proof of (4)" and "Proof of (5)" you mean "Proof of (3)" and "Proof of (4)", respectively. It would be simpler to describe "the bilinear form whose matrix is the identity" as "the dot product on $E^k$" and it would be useful if you clarified what the notation $Hb$ means. You should indicate that $(Hb)^\perp$ is stable under the action of $H$ since that is how you know $h(x) \in (Hb)^\perp$.

Comment: Dear @KCd: Thank you very much for your comment! I'll rewrite the answer taking your suggestions into account. I'm not sure when the new version will be ready, but when I post it, I'll let you know by a comment like this one.

Comment: Dear @KCD: Here is the new version. Thanks again!

Comment: I made a few other edits in the proof of (4) to make it more natural why one would want to look at $(Hb)^\perp$ when the inital interest is just in $b^\perp$.

Comment: Dear @KCd: Wonderful!!! --- I added a few words to [the second occurrence of] (2).

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Hello Pierre. Please check out my answer to this question. The proof of Claim 3 in my answer to me seems to simplify the overall argument.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard I also have a question. Is is true that if $f:V\times V\to F$ is a bilinear form on a vector space $V$ (with ground field $F$), and $W$ is a proper subspace of $V$, then $W^\perp$ is nonzero? I ask this because in the 'proof of (4)'  you seem to make use of this, at least by assuming $f$ is symmetric if required. I am unable to see this if $f$ is not non-degenerate on $W$. Can you please address this? Thanks.

Comment: @caffeinemachine - Thanks! I'll read your answer carefully, but please be patient: I'm very slow! About your bilinear form $f$, let's assume to simplify that $f$ is symmetric and that $\dim V<\infty$ (this suffices for our purpose). We can also assume that $f$ is non-degenerate, so that the map $g:V\to V^*$ defined by $g(v)(v')=f(v,v')$, which is clearly injective, is also surjective. Let $h$ be a nonzero linear form on $V$ which vanishes on $W$. Then there is a $v\in V$ such that $g(v)=h$, that is $v\in W^\perp$ (and obviously $v\neq0$).

Comment: @caffeinemachine - Your answer looks very nice to me! I upvoted it.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard So basically the bilinear form on $E^k$ (the dot product) is non-degenerate (something I missed to note before, somehow) which does our job.  And thank you for your upvote! Your answer has taught me a lot, though I need some time to fully absorb it. I don't know much Galois theory.

Comment: A pdf version can be found here: https://vixra.org/abs/1207.0051

Answer (score 9):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\aut}{Aut}$ $\newcommand{\vp}{\varphi}$Here is a short proof.

Let $E$ be the splitting field of a separable polynomial $p(x)$ over a field $F$. We need to show that $E:F$ is a separable extension.

**Claim 1.** $[E:F]=|\aut(E:F)|$.
**Proof.** Say $\deg p=n$ and let $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ be all the roots of $p$ in $E$. Write $F_i$ to denote $F(a_1, \ldots, a_i)$. We will show that each $F$-embedding of $F_i$ in $E$ admits exactly $[F_{i+1}:F_i]$ extensions to an embedding of $F_{i+1}$ into $E$.

Suppose $\vp:F_i\to E$ be an $F$-embedding of $F_i$ in $E$ and let $d_i=[F_{i+1}:F_i]$. We need to show that there are exactly $d_i$ different extensions of $\vp$ to an embedding of $F_{i+1}$ into $E$. Let $p_i(x)\in F_i[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $a_{i+1}$ over $F_i$. Since $p_i$ and $p$ both have $a_{i+1}$ has a root, we have $p_i|p$ and therefore $p_i$ has $d_i$ distinct roots in $E$. Now we may extend $\vp$ to $F_{i+1}$ by sending $a_{i+1}$ to any root of $p_i$ we wish. Further, all extensions of $\vp$ send $a_{i+1}$ to some root of $p_i$. Lastly, any extension of $\vp$ is determined completely by its action on $a_{i+1}$. Therefore there are precisely $d_i=[F_{i+1}:F_i]$ different extensions of $\vp$ to $F_{i+1}$.

Thus there are at least $[F_n:F_{n-1}]\cdots [F_1:F]=[E:F]$ distinct elements in $\aut(E:F)$. There cannot be any more and thus we are done. $\blacksquare$

**Claim 2.** The fixed field in $E$ of $\aut(E:F)$ is $F$.
**Proof.** Let $M$ be the fixed field of $\aut(E:F)$. Thus there is a natural bijection between $\aut(E:M)$ and $\aut(E:F)$. Note that $p(x)$ is a separable polynomial over $M$ whose splitting field is $E$. Therefore, by Claim 1, we have $|\aut(E:M)|=[E:M]$. This shows that $|\aut(E:F)|=[E:M]$. In the light of Claim 1, this is only possible if $M=F$. $\blacksquare$

**Claim 3.** $E$ is separable over $F$.
**Proof.** Let $\alpha\in E$ be chosen arbitrarily and $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$. We need to show that $f(x)$ is separable over $F$. Note that $E$ is normal over $F$ and therefore completely splits $f$. Write $f=(x-\beta_1)^{r_1}\cdots (x-\beta_k)^{r_k}$ in $E[x]$, where $\beta_i$'s are pairwise distinct. If $\vp\in \aut(E:F)$, then we see that
$$f=(x-\beta_1)^{r_1}\cdots (x-\beta_k)^{r_k}= (x-\vp(\beta_1))^{r_1}\cdots (x-\vp(\beta_k))^{r_k}$$
which lets us conclude that $\vp$ permutes $\{\beta_1, \ldots, \beta _k\}$. Since $\vp$ was arbitrary in $\aut(E:F)$, we conclude that $\aut(E:F)$ acts on $\{\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_k\}$. Therefore the symmetric functions on $\beta_i$'s remain fixed by $\aut(E:F)$. Applying Claim 2, we see that each symmetric function in $\beta_i$'s is a member of $F$. Therefore the polynomial $(x-\beta_1)\cdots (x-\beta_k)$ is in $F[x]$. Since $f(x)$ was irreducible over $F$, we are forced to have $f(x)=(x-\beta_1)\cdots (x-\beta_k)$ and we have shown that $\alpha$ is separable over $F$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Isn't claim 2 true by definition of Aut(E:F)? (Being the automorphism group on E that has F as its fixed field)

Comment: $\text{Aut}(E:F)$ is the set of all automorphisms of $E$ which fix $F$ (pointwise). Thus, a priori, an element of $\text{Aut}(E:F)$ may fix more than just $F$. In fact, if $E:F$ is a non-Galois algebriac extension then the fixed field of $\text{Aut}(E:F)$ is necessarily bigger than $F$.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying! If you don't mind, could you elaborate on where exactly the separability of p was used in the proof of claim 1?

Comment: @feltshire We used separability of $p$ when we said that "$p_i$ has $d_i$ distinct roots..."

Comment: In the proof of Claim 1, shouldn't $p_i$ be defined as the minimal polynomial of $a_{i+1}$ rather than $a_i$?

Comment: @Sirawit'Plum'P. Yes. You are right. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another proof that the splitting field for a separable polynomial is separable.

First use the fact, proven by caffeinemachine above, that if $E$ is a splitting field by a separable polynomial over $F$ then $|\text{Aut}(E/F)| = |E:F|$. A simple note from the proof is that if the splitting polynomial isn't separable, then the group of automorphisms has strictly smaller cardinality, since there are strictly fewer extensions when there are duplicate roots.

Then, use the following lemma:

Lemma 1. If $K$ is characteristic in $E$ fixing $F$ (if $K$ is stable under every automorphism of $E/F$), with $F \subseteq K \subseteq E$, then $|\text{Aut}(E/K)||\text{Aut}(K/F)| \geq |\text{Aut}(E/F)|$.

Proof. Consider the equivalence relation on $\text{Aut}(E/F)$ where $\sigma \sim \tau$ if $\sigma \circ \tau^{-1}$ fixes $K$. This relation is symmetric, reflexive, and transitive. It is easy to see that the size of each coset is $\text{Aut}(E/K)$, since automorphisms are invertible. Two automorphisms are in the same coset if and only if they restrict to the same automorphism on $K$ that fixes $F$, since $\sigma \circ \tau^{-1}$ fixes $K$. This restriction is possible since $K$ is characteristic. So, the number of cosets is smaller than the number of automorphisms on $K$ that fix $F$. This proves that $\frac{|\text{Aut}(E/F)|}{|\text{Aut}(E/K)|} \leq |\text{Aut}(K/F)|$.

Now, take an element $\alpha$ of $E$, with minimal polynomial $g(x)$. Assume by contradiction that it is not separable. Then we know that $\text{Aut}(K/F) < |K:F| $, where K is the splitting field of $g(x)$ over $F$. Note that $K \subseteq E$, since $\alpha \in E$ and any irreducible polynomial with a root in a splitting field splits. So, we find that $|\text{Aut}(E/K)||\text{Aut}(K/F)| < |E:K||K:F| = |E:F|$. To complete the proof, observe that $K$ is characteristic in $E/F$, since the generators (the roots of the splitting polynomial) must permute with each other. So, $|\text{Aut}(E/K)||\text{Aut}(K/F)| \geq |\text{Aut}(E/F)| = |E:F|$, a contradiction.